# Why My Data Table is not getting Displayed?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components

Class

```
public class CL_1303_Eg1_AccountTable {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Account> acl(String kw)
    {
        String Qr='Select Id,Name,Phone,Fax from Account where name like \'%' + kw + '%\'';
        List<account> AAA=Database.query(Qr);
        Return AAA;
    }

}
```

Component

```
<aura:component controller="CL_1303_Eg1_AccountTable" >
    <aura:attribute name="accnt" type="Account[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="Keyword" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="col" type="List"/>
    
    <lightning:card title="Account Search">
        <lightning:input value="{!v.Keyword}"/>
        <lightning:button label="Get Account Data" onclick="{!c.getme}"/>
    </lightning:card>
    
    <lightning:layout >
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.accnt}" var="a">
            <lightning:layoutitem size="3" padding="aroud-small">
                <lightning:card iconName="standard:account">
                    <aura:set attribute="title">
                        {!a.Name}
                    </aura:set>
                    Phone:{!a.Phone} <P></P>
                    Fax:{!a.Fax}     <p></p>
                    Industry:{!a.Industry} <p></p>
                </lightning:card>
            </lightning:layoutitem>
        </aura:iteration>
    </lightning:layout>
    
    <lightning:dataTable KeyField="id" data="{!v.accnt}" columns="{!v.colms}"/>
    
</aura:component>
```

Controller

```
    getme : function(component, event, helper) {
        var clm=[
            {label:"Account Name",fieldName:"Name",type:"text"},
            {label:"Account Phone",fieldName:"Phone",type:"phone"},
            {label:"Account Fax",fieldName:"Fax"},
            {label:"Account Industry",fieldName:"Industry",type:"text"}
        ];
        component.set("v.colms",clm);
        var key=component.get("v.Keyword");
        var MM=component.get("c.acl");
        MM.setParams({"kw":key});
        MM.setCallback(this,function(response){
            var state=response.getState();
            if(state=='SUCCESS')
            {
                var result=response.getReturnValue();
                component.set("v.accnt",result);
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(MM);
    }
})
```

Application

````
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <c:CL_1303_Eg1_AccountDataTile/>    
</aura:application>```
````

Comment: There are a number of mistakes here in capitalization and in spelling/declaration, in addition to sfdcfox's answer. `KeyField` should be `keyField`, and `v.colms` should be `v.col`. `aroud-small` should be `around-small`. You must be careful and rigorous about identifiers or your code will not work.

Comment: @DavidReed Tqsm..David. I am new to Salesforce. I am learning a lot from people like you.  I always try to learn from my mistakes and not repeat them again. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pay attention carefully to the documentation. It's `lightning:datatable`, not `lightning:dataTable`. Lightning is completely cAsE-sEnSiTiVe, for element names, attributes, properties, parameters, and so on.